# PHP, PDO, MySQL get counts and Median with conditions

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am trying to solve a problem relating to data in a MySQL DB.

I have a table that holds results from people completing work. There are multiple projects, and multiple users that do the projects. Each entry in the table holds, among other fields:

- Project Number
- User ID
- Status
- Duration

The Status can be 1, 2 or 3

```
Proj Num   | User ID        | Status | Duration
20001      |sdvdsv3-3ed3dd  |    1   |  8.3
20001      |dfggsv3-3ed54dd |    1   |  8.9
20001      |sdghfgs-3edfgdd |    1   |  11.5
20001      |sdfbvv3-3ed3dd  |    1   |  10.6
20001      |sdsdfv3-3ed3dd  |    1   |  15.2
20001      |dfxxdv3-3gbb4dd |    2   |  1.3
20002      |45gdvv3-3gbb4dd |    1   |  12
20002      |45lu5v3-3ger4dd |    2   |  1.1
20002      |45lu5v3-34r4dd  |    2   |  0.9
20002      |fv333v3-3g543d  |    2   |  0.6
```

My end goal is to show, back in my admin portal, the number of '1's, '2's and '3's for each project - which must be in an open status that is set in a Projects table, as well as the **median duration**.  Median is causing me grief as to my knowledge there is no native query. I have tried so many different examples, I started looking to just get all the data, take it back to PHP and somehow process it there.

Ideally, I'd like to do it all with SQL query.

I am just stuck on the right approach to solve this.  I am happy to answer any questions with details I have missed (probably as I don't know they are pertinent to the problem/solution).

**EDIT :**

pseudo code:

```
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM project_end end JOIN projects pr ON end.prNum = pr.prNum WHERE end.status = 1 AND pr.status = 'Open') AS totalComplete
```

I need to do that multiple times for each end status (1, 2 or 3), and group the counts by the project number.

In addition I need to calculate the median duration for each project

The final data is fed back as an ajax response.

I am not sure what I need to be searching for in order to find examples/tutorials that I can adjust to fit my scenario

**EDIT 2 :**

Further to @Strawberry's comments, I have a Projects table that has a record for each project, including whether the project is Open or Closed.

When users complete tasks for each project, this is recorded in Project_End table.

For my output, I only want to see the information for those projects that are still in an open status.

Comment: There are plenty of examples of interpolating a median. I don't know what "which must be in an open status that is set in a Projects table" means.

Comment: Thanks for reading @Strawberry .  I have edited my first post to hopefully (but probably badly) explain my predicament a little better.

I don't know if the best approach is to do it all in a giant SQL query, or to get the 'raw' data back to PHP and try to process it there, get it into an object somehow and send back to the requesting AJAX script for display.

Comment: The best approach would be a join